# How to set translations in javascripts for my plugin?

Tags: javascript, translation, xgettext

I have in my plugin :

- form.js : js script to do a custom validation on form fields
- js_lang.php : based on this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400106/translation-in-javascript-like-gettext-in-php)
- my-plugin-domain-fr_FR.po

In **form.js**, I use a var (msg_must_match) from js_lang.php

```
function inputsMatch( inputTypes, idInputReferring, idInputRepeat ){
        var inputReferring = document.getElementById( idInputReferring );
        var inputRepeat = document.getElementById( idInputRepeat );

        var checkPasswordValidity = function() {
            if (inputReferring.value != inputRepeat.value) {
                inputRepeat.setCustomValidity( msg_must_match /*<-- here*/ );
            } else {
                inputRepeat.setCustomValidity('');
            }
        };
        inputReferring.addEventListener('change', checkPasswordValidity, false);
        inputRepeat.addEventListener('change', checkPasswordValidity, false);
}
```

In my **js_lang.php** I try to manage the translation loading my-plugin-domain-fr_FR.po without success

```
$locale = "fr_FR";

putenv("LANG=".$locale); 
setlocale('LC_ALL', $locale); 
bindtextdomain("my-plugin-domain", "./locale/");  
textdomain("my-plugin-domain");
$str = 'It is must match with the previous input';
?>
msg_must_match = "<?php echo gettext( $str ); ?>"
```

I do not manage to load correctly the .po file.
Someone could help me ?
Is there a easier wordpress way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WordPress way to do this is the `wp_localize_script()` function.

When you enqueue a script, also add a call to `wp_localize_script()`:

```
wp_register_script( 'my-script', 'path/to/script.js' );
wp_localize_script( 'my-script', 'myScript', array(
    'msg_must_match' => __( 'Message must match', 'my-plugin-domain' ),
) );
```

This creates a global JavaScript object called `myScript` that will contain the keys and values passed as an array in the 3rd argument. So you can pass in strings using the WordPress translation functions, which will get translated just like any other string in your plugin.

Then in your script you can use those values for your strings:

```
inputRepeat.setCustomValidity( myScript.msg_must_match );
```